# Delete row in Parse Data browser. So my TableViewController gets updated with the correct amount of cells minus the deleted cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

```
import UIKit

class FavouritesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let factBook = FactBook()

    var userQuoteData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    let colorWheel = ColorWheel()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("loadData"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.refreshControl = refreshControl

        self.loadData()


        //********** For resizbale cells UILABEL **************//
//        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 102 // Replace with your actual estimation
//        // Automatic dimensions to tell the table view to use dynamic height
//        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        //********** For resizbale cells UILABEL **************//

//        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
//            var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up / Login", message: "Please sign up or login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
//            
//            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
//                textfield in
//                textfield.placeholder = "Your username"
//            })
//            
//            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
//                textfield in
//                textfield.secureTextEntry = true
//                textfield.placeholder = "Your password"
//            })
//            
//            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
//                alertAction in
//                let textField:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields as NSArray!
//                let usernameTextField:UITextField = textField.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
//                let passwoordTextField:UITextField = textField.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField
//                
//                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text, password: passwoordTextField.text, block: { (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//                    if ((user) != nil) {
//                        println("Login Successful")
//                    }else {
//                        println("Login Failed")
//                    }
//                })
//            }))
//            
//            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Signup", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
//                alertAction in
//                let textField:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields as NSArray!
//                let usernameTextField:UITextField = textField.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
//                let passwoordTextField:UITextField = textField.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField
//                
//                var user:PFUser = PFUser()
//                user.username = usernameTextField.text
//                user.password = passwoordTextField.text
//                
//                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (sucsess: Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//                    if error == nil {
//                        println("Sign Up sucessful")
//                    } else {
//                        let error = error.userInfo
//                        println(error)
//                    }
//                })
//                
//            }))
//            
//            self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
//            
//        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: Segue to Main View Controller

    @IBAction func CancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    //MARK: logout the user
    @IBAction func logoutUser(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
            // ...
        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in

            PFUser.logOut()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedQuoteSegue", sender: nil)

            var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this will now be nil
            println(currentUser)

        }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }

    }

    // MARK: Getting Quotes from Parse.com for a particular user

    func loadData() {

        userQuoteData.removeAllObjects()

        var findUserQuoteData: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "favouriteQuotes")
        findUserQuoteData.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())

        findUserQuoteData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil{
                for object in objects{
                    let user: PFObject = object as PFObject
                    self.userQuoteData.addObject(user)
                }

                let array:NSArray = self.userQuoteData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.userQuoteData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }

        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return userQuoteData.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:FavouritesTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as FavouritesTableViewCell

        let favouriteQuotes:PFObject = self.userQuoteData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

        cell.favouriteQuoteTextView.text = favouriteQuotes.objectForKey("content") as? String

        cell.favouriteQuoteTextView.backgroundColor = colorWheel.randomColor()
        //Label Animation
        cell.favouriteQuoteTextView.alpha = 0

        //Date Formatter
//        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
//        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
//        cell.timestampLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

        //Find User
//        var findSweeter:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
//        findSweeter.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: sweet.objectForKey("sweeter").objectId)
//        
//        findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//            if error == nil {
//                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
//                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username


                //Animation automation
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                    cell.favouriteQuoteTextView.alpha = 1
                })
//            }
//        
//        }

        cell.favouriteQuoteTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        let cell:FavouritesTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as FavouritesTableViewCell

        var selectedQuoteFromFavourites: AnyObject = self.userQuoteData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)

        var selectedQuote: String = selectedQuoteFromFavourites.objectForKey("content") as String!

        println(selectedQuote)

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selectedQuote, forKey: "currentQuote") // we are saving a variable called myName and we are giving it the value of "Bob"
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() // Added synchronize as suggested by LAMMERT WESTERHOFF
                println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentQuote")!) // Here we are accessing the variable.

//                    factBook.currentQuoteIndexArray()

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "segueHappened") // we are saving a variable called myName and we are giving it the value of "Bob"
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() // Added synchronize as suggested by LAMMERT WESTERHOFF
                    //                        println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("segueHappened")) // Here we are accessing the variable.

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedQuoteSegue", sender: AnyObject?())

    }

    //MARK: Swipe to delete
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //MARK: Deleting Object PFQuery
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

            println("touch")

//            var selectedQuoteFromFavourites: AnyObject = self.userQuoteData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
//            
//            var selectedQuote: String = selectedQuoteFromFavourites.objectForKey("content") as String!
//            
//            println(selectedQuote)

            //Query objectId from parse and delete!

//            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I have this loadData() function that gets all the Quotes that a user has stored to my Parse backend. I think it puts the data received from parse into this NSMutable array "userQuoteData". This is what my tableview uses to populate the cells. I added a swipe to delete function at the bottom of this code. it looks like this:

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
```

within this swipe to delete function: 
How do I tell parse to delete the corrent row with the content of the current cell that is selected(swiped). so I can then reloadData on that tableview with my amended list of quotes from parse. Do I need to find the objectId? Really lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `self.userQuoteData` to contain the full `PFObjects` so simply delete the object; and you'll need to remove the selected object from the `self.userQuoteData` array before reloading since it informs your table data.

Also, your Parse table doesn't inform your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` directly at all -- the `self.userQuoteData` array does -- so the Parse table doesn't technically need to be updated in order for your table to reflect the changes. So like I've done in the code below, you can delete your object from Parse in the background even as your table reloads.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        var selectedQuoteFromFavourites:PFObject = self.userQuoteData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject
        selectedQuoteFromFavourites.deleteInBackground()
        self.userQuoteData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: what if the object is still waiting for a save, via saveEventually? Then it will not be deleted. Any idea how to do this ?